# Gatsby Server Rendering APIs - How can I remove the 3 meta tags in default-html.js without copying file to src folder?

Tags: gatsby

Quick Q.

I know I can tweak the build using gatsby-ssr.js (see below for example)

```
exports.onPreRenderHTML = ({ pathname, getHeadComponents, replaceHeadComponents }, pluginOptions) => {
    if (pathname.includes(_esi)) {
        let headComponents = getHeadComponents()
        headComponents = headComponents.filter(item => item.type === style)
        replaceHeadComponents(headComponents)
    }
}
```

But how can I remove the 3 core meta tags added in .cache/default-html.js WITHOUT copying it and editing it in src?

Answer (score 0):

I had to copy default html to src folder, remove the hard coded metas, and add back via react helmet in layout.js which wraps all other pages.